# Sum the Column based on another column

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

i have a file with 2 columns, 1st column is time with HH:MM:SS  format and 2nd column is count.
I want to sum the 2nd column based 1st coulmn. with respect to Hour and minute of 1st column.

Input:

```
00:00:00,2.00,
00:00:10,1.00,
00:00:20,2.00,
00:00:30,6.00,
00:00:40,1.00,
00:00:50,7.00,
00:01:00,8.00,
00:01:10,7.00,
00:01:20,8.00,
00:01:30,11.00,
```

For Hour: the below awk works,

```
 awk -F, '{ a[substr($1,0,2)]+=$2 } END{ for (i in a) print i "," a[i] }' file
```

output:

```
00,53
```

For Minute:
unable sum the column based on the Minute filed, please suggesst the way to get the expected result.

Excepted Output:

```
00:00,19
00:01,34
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `awk:

```
awk -F '[:,]' -v OFS=, '{s[$1 ":" $2]+=$(NF-1)} END{for (i in s) print i, s[i]}' file
00:00,19
00:01,34
```

---

**EDIT:** If ordering of original timestamps is important then use:

```
awk -F '[:,]' -v OFS=, '{k=$1":"$2} !s[k]{b[++n]=k} {s[k]+=$(NF-1)}
     END {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i], s[b[i]]}' file
00:00,19
00:01,34
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain the regex part.

Comment: Much better solution. You do not need to handle the formatting.

Comment: @Marjer: This works by using a custom field separator `[,:]` which means comma or colon. That makes `$1` holds hour part and `$2` holds minute part. `$(NF-1)` holds actual value. `s` is associative array with key as `hour:minute` (`$1 ":" $2`) and values are summed together using `+=`.

Comment: Do to the random output from `(i in s)` it may print 02:34 before 01:20.  So a `sort` may be needed.

Comment: I can avoid sort actually using awk itself. Let me update it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add minutes to the hour and then count.

```
awk -F, '{ a[substr($1,0,2)+substr($1,4,2)]+=$2 } END{ for (i in a) print i "," a[i] }'
0,19
1,34
```

Then you may use some math and `printf` to get formating.

Comment: Amazing, Is it possible to include the Hour Filed in the result. 00:00,19 00:01,34

Comment: @Marjer anubhava is better :)